# How to center data in a python dataframe?

Tags: python

I'm sure this is a pretty simple thing but I'm new to python and I can't figure this out. I have a dataframe containing a series of numbers. For each value in the dataframe I would like to go through each column and subtract the mean of that column from each value and divide it by the standard deviation. I know this involves some sort of for loop but I can't figure out the syntax to pull this off.

Comment: Your goals is to standardize data ?

Comment: https://www.statology.org/standardize-data-python/

Comment: You don't need a loop. Take a look at pandas `apply` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(4,3)))

def standardize(x):
    y = x - x.mean()
    sd = x.std()
    return y / sd
df.apply( standardize, axis=0)
```

using axis=0 means operate on columns